# Simplest way to check if two integers have same sign?

Tags: integer, bit-manipulation, sign

Which is the simplest way to check if two integers have same sign? Is there any short bitwise trick to do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is a version that works in C/C++ that doesn't rely on integer sizes or have the overflow problem (i.e. x*y>=0 doesn't work)

```
bool SameSign(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 0) ^ (y < 0);
}
```

Of course, you can geek out and template:

```
template <typename valueType>
bool SameSign(typename valueType x, typename valueType y)
{
    return (x >= 0) ^ (y < 0);
}
```

Note: Since we are using exclusive or, we want the LHS and the RHS to be different when the signs are the same, thus the different check against zero.

Comment: Quite nice, the C/C++ hacker in me fully supports this code snippet. The software engineer in me questions why the user needs to know this in such a generic manner!

Comment: Doesn't this fail if x=0 and y>0?

Answer (score 248):

What's wrong with

```
return ((x<0) == (y<0));
```

?

Comment: Um... Nothing...

Sad that we all missed the simple solution.

Comment: What about Signed zero. -0.0 vs Unsigned zero 0.0

Comment: @Ólafur: OP specified integers, not floats.

Comment: This assumes that you want to consider 0 as being the same sign as a positive integer.

Comment: @ÓlafurWaage At least in JavaScript, the following is true [`-0===+0`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.6), so it's not an issue there.

Comment: **Never settle for an accepted answer! Always be curious! Maybe it's time for SO, to reconsider the true meaning of an accepted answer. SO should modify the true meaning of accepted answer, so that the most relevant ones float on the top. Else, most lazy geeks like me don't even bother to scroll for alternatives.**

Comment: @taurus05 you can order answers by highest score or trending score. Even if you don't read down the bottom, in general others will and this should bring the new better answers to the top. Like this one has.

Answer (score 40):

```
(a ^ b) >= 0
```

will evaluate to 1 if the sign is the same, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Oh, nice!  :-)  I'm surprised that I missed this one.  The really nice thing about this solution is it doesn't depend upon a particular bit cardinality in the underlying integer representation.

Comment: This one results in the delightfully compact "xorl %edi, %esi; sets %al" on x86, only 6 bytes and two instructions. It's also an interesting case study as it's a concrete case where returning a 'bool' instead of an int produces dramatically better code.

Comment: @JohnMeacham : Wondering what you mean by 'it's a concrete case where returning a 'bool' instead of an int produces dramatically better code'

Answer (score 12):

I would be wary of any bitwise tricks to determine the sign of integers, as then you have to make assumptions about how those numbers are represented internally.

Almost 100% of the time, integers will be stored as [two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_Compliment), but it's not good practice to make assumptions about the internals of a system unless you are using a datatype that guarentees a particular storage format.

In two's compliment, you can just check the last (left-most) bit in the integer to determine if it is negative, so you can compare just these two bits. This would mean that 0 would have the same sign as a positive number though, which is at odds with the sign function implemented in most languages.

Personally, I'd just use the sign function of your chosen language. It is unlikely that there would be any performance issues with a calculation such as this.

Comment: The C Standard Lib provides a signbit() function. Probably tough to beat the optimiser with any "bitwise tricks" of your own devising.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming 32 bit ints:

```
bool same = ((x ^ y) >> 31) != 1;
```

Slightly more terse:

```
bool same = !((x ^ y) >> 31);
```

Comment: Those two code examples should ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS be preceded by a code comment please (in real life)

Comment: Oh, of course. In real life, I'd probably use something like same = Math.Sign(x) == Math.Sign(y). I just give evil bitwidily solutions when people ask for them. :D

Comment: Um, this is not valid code... how do you expect `& >>` to work?

Comment: It wasn't. I have no idea what I was thinking with that and sign 10 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

(integer1 * integer2) > 0

Because when two integers share a sign, the result of multiplication will always be positive.

You can also make it >= 0 if you want to treat 0 as being the same sign no matter what.

Comment: If one of the integers are 0, then you've got a problem.

Comment: 0 is neither negative nor positive so it technically would not be the same sign.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure I'd consider "bitwise trick" and "simplest" to be synonymous.  I see a lot of answers that are assuming signed 32-bit integers (though it *would* be silly to ask for unsigned); I'm not certain they'd apply to floating-point values.

It seems like the "simplest" check would be to compare how both values compare to 0; this is pretty generic assuming the types can be compared:

```
bool compare(T left, T right)
{
    return (left < 0) == (right < 0);
}
```

If the signs are opposite, you get false.  If the signs are the same, you get true.

Comment: false && false == false

I'm afraid that you would need to make that the negation of an XOR in order to make it correct.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming twos complement arithmetic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_complement):

```
inline bool same_sign(int x, int y) {
    return (x^y) >= 0;
}
```

This can take as little as two instructions and less than 1ns on a modern processor with optimization.

Not assuming twos complement arithmetic:

```
inline bool same_sign(int x, int y) {
    return (x<0) == (y<0);
}
```

This may require one or two extra instructions and take a little longer.

Using multiplication is a bad idea because it is vulnerable to overflow.

Answer (score 3):

if (x * y) > 0...

assuming non-zero and such.

Answer (score 2):

As a technical note, bit-twiddly solutions are going to be much more efficient than multiplication, even on modern architectures.  It's only about 3 cycles that you're saving, but you know what they say about a "penny saved"...

Comment: a penny saved is the root of all evil, say about 97% of the time?

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head...

```
int mask = 1 << 31;
(a & mask) ^ (b & mask) < 0;
```

Comment: only works for 32 bit ints, which was not stipulated in the question

Answer (score 1):

if (a*b < 0) sign is different, else sign is the same (or a or b is zero)

Answer (score 1):

For any size of int with two's complement arithmetic:

```
#define SIGNBIT (~((unsigned int)-1 >> 1))
if ((x & SIGNBIT) == (y & SIGNBIT))
    // signs are the same
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming 32 bit

`if(((x^y) & 0x80000000) == 0)`

... the answer `if(x*y>0)` is bad due to overflow

Answer (score 1):

branchless C version:

```
int sameSign(int a, int b) {
    return ~(a^b) & (1<<(sizeof(int)*8-1));
}
```

C++ template for integer types:

```
template <typename T> T sameSign(T a, T b) {
    return ~(a^b) & (1<<(sizeof(T)*8-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking back to my university days, in most machine representations, isn't the left-most bit of a integer a 1 when the number is negative, and 0 when it's positive?

I imagine this is rather machine-dependent, though.

Answer (score 0):

int same_sign = !( (x >> 31) ^ (y >> 31) );

if ( same_sign ) ...
else             ...

Answer (score 0):

Better way using [std::signbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) as follows:

```
std::signbit(firstNumber) == std::signbit(secondNumber);
```

It also support other basic types (`double`, `float`, `char` etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int checksign(int a, int b)
{
 return (a ^ b); 
}

void  main()
{
    int a=-1, b = 0;

    if(checksign(a,b)<0)
    {
        printf("Integers have the opposite sign");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Integers have the same sign");
    }
}
```