# Check if two integers have the same sign

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for an efficient way to check if two numbers have the same sign.

Basically I'm searching for a more elegant way than this:

```
var n1 = 1;
var n2 = -1;

( (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0) || (n1<0 && n2 < 0) )? console.log("equal sign"):console.log("different sign");
```

A solution with bitwise operators would be fine too.

Comment: It's not JavaScript, but I guess all of these work as well: [Simplest way to check if two integers have same sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66882/simplest-way-to-check-if-two-integers-have-same-sign).

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, i read this question but stopped at the accepted answer, which i wasn't satisfied with;)

Comment: Well, the [next answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67498/218196) is pretty cool imo: `return ((x<0) ==(y<0));`.

Comment: @FelixKling thats true, another case for "Don't stop reading after accepted answer"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fewer characters of code, but might underflow for very small numbers:

```
n1*n2 > 0 ? console.log("equal sign") : console.log("different sign or zero");
```

Note: As @tsh correctly mentioned, an overflow with an intermediate result of `Infinity` or `-Infinity` does work. But an underflow with an intermediate result of `+0` or `-0` will fail, because `+0` is not bigger than `0`.

or without underflow, but slightly larger:

```
(n1<0) == (n2<0) ? console.log("equal sign") : console.log("different sign");
```

Comment: What if `n1` and `n2` are both positive integers but multiplying them causes an integer overlow?

Comment: Than the first version fails. So i added a more robust but slightly larger version.

Comment: by using this expression, you need assume that both n1 and n2 are number type and not NaN.

Comment: Overflow does not matter. (Infinity just works fine.) But underflow does.

Answer (score 59):

You can multiply them together; if they have the same sign, the result will be positive.

```
bool sameSign = (n1 * n2) > 0
```

Comment: What if `n1` and `n2` are both positive integers but multiplying them causes an integer overlow?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I was worried someone would point that out ;) -- in that case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66882/simplest-way-to-check-if-two-integers-have-same-sign

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar this problem won't occur in my case, but nevertheless worth pointing this out.

Comment: What if `n1` and `n2` are both zero?

Comment: @Matthew: That's actually more tricky. In JavaScript there exists `+0` and `-0`... seems like bit operations are necessary here. Of course if you don't care to differ between these two zeros, a simple `n1 === n2` is sufficient...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar JavaScript will never cause integer overflow on Number type, since they are not "integers" at all. They are float, IEEE 754 float.

Comment: God knows why @ThorstenDittmar got so many upvotes. As tsh pointed out, JavaScript does not have integer overflows and underflows because JavaScript doesn't have integers (excluding BigNum, but those can't overflow either)

Answer (score 11):

Use bitwise xor

```
n1^n2 >= 0 ? console.log("equal sign") : console.log("different sign");
```

Comment: testing for `< 0` will make it one char smaller ;)

Answer (score 6):

That based on how you define "same sign" for special values:

- does `NaN`, `NaN` have the same sign?

If your answer is "No", the answer is:

```
Math.sign(a) === Math.sign(b)
```

If your answer is "Yes", the answer is:

```
Object.is(Math.sign(a) + 0, Math.sign(b) + 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the correct answer would be "Yes" and "Yes", and thus this approach is not particularly useful (besides the fact, that it is not really practical to invoke the `Math` object for such a trivial task).

Comment: @Christoph YY and NN had been added to the answer.

Comment: @Christoph I cannot understand why you do not want use methods in ES Spec. You do not need add dependency to any third party cods, and they should work better than most codes other people wrote. You may say this task is "trivial", but I did not find other answers handle these edge cases correctly. You may say "it is not my business for my specified question", but that should not be a "correct" answer to this question.

Comment: I removed the `+-0` part, since the spec clearly states, how to treat this case. I think you misunderstood my comment - I know that this is a native object, I just think, that it's "overkill" to use it, if there are simpler solutions (besides the fact, that I was looking for a short solution). Nonetheless, I gave you an upvote for your "outside-the-box" solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = n1*n2;
if(n>0){ same sign }
else { different sign }
```

Comment: What if `n1` and `n2` are both positive integers but multiplying them causes an integer overlow?

Comment: agreed. that might be a problem.

Answer (score -5):

Maybe a regex should do the trick

```
function isNegative(num) { 
        if (num.match(/^-\d+$/)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
   }


function isSameSign(num1, num2) { 
        var sameSign = false;  
        if (num1.match(/^-\d+$/) && num2.match(/^-\d+$/) ) {
                sameSign = true;
            } else if(!num2.match(/^-\d+$/) && !num2.match(/^-\d+$/)) {
                sameSign =true;
            }
        return sameSign;
       }
```

Comment: This only returns whether one number is false. If you want to do that, you can just check `num > 0` -- to convert a string to a number first you can do `parseInt(num) > 0`

Comment: Well it just requires a tweak. I have updated and given a second version to show, how the first function can be modified to achieve the requirement

Comment: But you're still using a fragile regex instead of the built-in `parseInt` method.

Comment: Even `return num1<0 && num2<0 || num1>=0 && num2>=0;` better and shorter