# Followup: Check if two integers have the same sign

Tags: javascript

I experimented with the bitwise-operator suggested [to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298109/check-if-two-integers-have-the-same-sign) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968/1047823).

Check the results of my testsuite:

```
function equal(n1,n2){
    var bool = (n1^n2 >= 0)?true:false;
    document.write("<div>"+bool+" ("+(n1^n2)+")</div>");
}


equal(-5,-2);  //true
equal(-4,-20); //true
equal(15,-2);  //false
equal(25,3);   //true 

equal(-1,1);   //false
equal(1,1);    //true
equal(-1,-1);  //true

// edgecases
equal(0,0);
equal(-0,0);
equal(+0,0);
equal(-0,+0);
equal(+0,-0);
```

outcome:

```
true (5)
true (16)
true (-15)
true (26)

true (-2)
false (0)
true (0)

true (0)
true (0)
true (0)
true (0)
true (0)
```

My according [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/qSwFt/).

The result confuses me very much. Am I too stupid? What has happened here?

Comment: You're not stupid, Javascript has some really interesting behavior with numbers approaching zero. Read this: http://www.2ality.com/2012/03/signedzero.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had your parentheses in the wrong place:

```
function equal(n1, n2){
    var bool = (n1 ^ n2) >= 0 ? true : false;
    document.write("<div>" + bool + " (" + (n1^n2) + ")</div>");
}
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSwFt/1/) with results matching what you expect.

This is important in this case because all of the bitwise operators are of [lower precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the  relational comparison operators. Also note that the conditional operator (`?:`) is of lower precedence than all of the bitwise operators, so there's no need for another set of parentheses around the entire condition.

Comment: ah, damn that operator binding^^ TY very much.