# Why doesn't bitwise xor work in an if statement of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

Could somebody explain this behavior?

https://jsfiddle.net/td1qtyxL/9/

```
function checkSignsWeird(a,b){
    var output = "";
    if(a^b < 0){
        output = "The "+a+" and "+b+" have DIFFERENT signs.";
    }else{
        output = "The "+a+" and "+b+" have the SAME sign.";
    }
    console.log(output);
}
```

Basically unless `a^b` is stored in a variable (or wrapped in parentheses), it doesn't work.

```
checkSignsWeird(-50,40);
checkSignsWeird(60,70);
```

Both produce the same result.

Amy I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Does bitwise work differently when it's in an if clause or when it's elsewhere? I don't often work with bitwise, just thought this was elegant, following up on an answer from here: [Check if two integers have the same sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298109/check-if-two-integers-have-the-same-sign)

Comment: Please specify your programming language. It looks like JS

Comment: Sorry I forgot :)

Comment: Perhaps [*operator precedence*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Less Than" (<) has a higher precedence than the bitwise XOR (^): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

You need to group the operation with parentheses.

Comment: So what is does without parentheses is that it first checks if `b < 0` (b is 40 or 70), evaluates it to `false` then continues by doing `-50^false` which is `-50` that counts as true...

Just to test if I understood correctly I ran `checkSignsWeird(0,1);` and it finally shown the result from the else branch. `1 < 0` means false then it does `0^false` which evaluates to `0` which is in turn false. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise operators have a lower precedence than comparison operators. See [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

That being said, don't write clever code.

```
function haveSameSign(a, b) {
    return (a >= 0 && b >= 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0);
}
```

Comment: Why not? Isn't this how we learn? Is there a scenario where clever is preferred over the trivial solution?

Comment: "Clever" code is non-obvious, hard to maintain, error-prone and usually serves no purpose other than stroking the ego of the one who wrote it. Avoid. Write dead-obvious code that does not need comments to be understood.