# C Macro equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, macros

The following macro is to determine if two numbers
have the same sign, is for 2's complement number
representation.

```
#define SAME_SIGNS( a, b )  (((long) ((unsigned long) a ^ (unsigned long) b)) >= 0 )
```

Can anyone suggest a javascript equivalent function?

Comment: In other words -- Could someone please translate that macro in javascript function?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: literal translate: `function sameSigns(a, b) { return (((a >>> 0) ^ (b >>> 0)) | 0) >= 0; }` // But notice that a, b are FLOAT in NOT INTEGER, so the implementation is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(a < 0 === b < 0)
```

or

```
(a * b > 0) // If one of a or b is 0, can't tell.
```

or

```
(a < 0 && b < 0 || a > 0 && b > 0)
```

true -> same, else different

Comment: Shorter version with no risk of overflow `return ((a<0) == (b<0));` (Adapted from [Rik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5409/rik)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67498/664577))

Comment: Nailed it :). I suggest you to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be exactly the same, but how about something like `!(a*b<0)`?